# reference request for the impact of priors in bayesian statistics

Tags: bayesian, inference, references, prior, map-estimation

It is well known that in bayesian statistics, the prior believe can have a large impact on the estimation result. For example if you flip a coin ten times to determine whether it is loaded,  a prior $p(loaded) = 1$ will result in estimates of $\hat{p}(loaded) =1$ irrespective of the data.

I am looking for a reference which discuss the impact of the prior on bayesian estimation results in some detail, focusing not only on the extreme case provided in my example (ideally a text book or a paper, something citeable).

Comment: The phenomenon in your example (the prior entirely determines the posterior, regardless of the data) is well-known and often referred to as [Cromwell's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromwell%27s_rule).

Comment: thanks, I was looking for a more general discussion of the impact of the prior (focusing on not just the case in the limit as in my example)

Answer (score 0):

The MAP idea is to find the set of parameters $\hat{\theta}_{\mathrm{MAP}}$ which maximizes the posterior probability $p(\theta|X,y)$, in other words, the most *likely* parameter vector.
Using Bayes' rule and (for the last step) assuming statistical independence between individual samples, one obtains

$$
 \hat{\theta}_{\mathrm{MAP}} = \arg\max_\theta p(\theta|X,y) = \arg\max_\theta \frac{p(y|X,\theta) p(\theta)}{p(y|X)} \\
 = \arg\max_\theta p(y|X,\theta) p(\theta) = \arg\max_\theta \log p(y|X,\theta) p(\theta) \\ 
 = \arg\max_\theta \log p(\theta) + \sum_{i=1}^N \log p(y_i|x_i,\theta)
$$

Now the first term represents the influence of the prior, and the second term the influence of the data. Obviously, the influence of the data grow with $N$, whereas the influence of the prior stays constant. Therefore, in most instances, MAP estimates converge towards ML estimates, which is a consequence of the [Bernstein-von Mises theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%E2%80%93von_Mises_theorem).

There are, of course, counterexamples in which the theorem does not hold and things go wrong, see, e.g., [Diagonis and Freedman, "On the consistency of Bayes estimates"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2241255). This is probably true for the example you gave (I have not verified that explicitly).

If you're not interested in all the technical details and just want something to cite, [Murphy's Machine Learning: A probabilistic perspective](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/MLbook/), p.68-70 would be a good choice. I still recommend understanding the details, though. :)